# Why do I get an undefined error when calling a function without parameter?

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I don't find the mistake, what am I doing wrong? It has to be a stupid and very easy reason...

When calling this function without a parameter the current year should be used in the following code but I get an 'undefined' error

```
function get_ostersonntag(year){
    if ((year == "") || (year == null)){
        year= new Date();
        year = year.getFullYear;

    }

    console.log(year)
  }
```

Comment: because `year` is passed with the value `undefined` and hence it doesn't go inside the `if` condition?

Comment: but even when I edit the function with year default null the same error occures?
 function blaala(year=null){etc.

Comment: Well, you miss the parenthesis in `getFullYear();`

Comment: What's the error? It works for me (the value of `year` becomes `undefined`, but `undefined == null` is `true`, so the `if` statement gets passed). It logs a function value for me, because `year.getFullYear` is a function - you probably meant `year = year.getFullYear()`

Comment: Thank you @LGSon! This was the problem. As mentioned...stupid and very easy reason :)

Comment: sorry @LGSon, I'd missed your comment somehow, and just posted mine (with the same content) as an answer :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you missed are the parentheses after `year = year.getFullYear`

```js
function get_ostersonntag(year){
    if ((year == "") || (year == null)){
        year= new Date();
        year = year.getFullYear();
    }
    console.log(year)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function works fine - when you call it with no arguments, the `year` argument is implicitly assigned to the `undefined` value. And `undefined == null` is true, so the `if` block is executed.

What I suspect is confusing you is that you have returned `year.getFullYear`, which is a function value. I think you want to actually *call* this function to get the result:

```js
function get_ostersonntag(year){
    if ((year == "") || (year == null)){
        year= new Date();
        year = year.getFullYear();

    }

    console.log(year)
  }

get_ostersonntag()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `year` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), that are values like empty string `''`, `null`, `undefined`, `false`, but zero `0` as well and `NaN` and check if `year` is not zero.

```js
function get_ostersonntag(year) {
    if (!year && year !== 0) {
        return new Date().getFullYear();
    }
    return year;
}

console.log(get_ostersonntag());
console.log(get_ostersonntag(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanx all. 
The reason was the missing brackets after .getFullYear

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
function get_ostersonntag(year){
    if (!year){
        year= new Date();
        year = year.getFullYear;

    }

    console.log(year)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your if condition:

```
function get_ostersonntag(year){
    if (!year) {
        year= new Date();
        year = year.getFullYear();
    }

    console.log(year)
  }
```

whenever year has falsy value (undefined, null or ''), it will go inside the if loop.